# Passing Command Line Argument to SwitchCase in AutoIt

Tags: command-line-arguments, autoit

I have a script that has a GUI and I have been running with a start button using the below code:

```
    Case $StartButton
```

I would also like to try scheduling this using Windows TaskScheduler to run every morning at 8 AM EST. What would be the best way to add a condition to either start with the start button OR when TaskScheduler runs at 8 AM EST (or any specific time)? I am hesitant to just do 8 AM condition as it may increase processing a lot always looking at the time.

Essentially what I am looking to have happen is for my computer to auto-unlock (login?) using task scheduler and run this AutoIt script which has been compiled to exe.

FilePath is:  C:\Users\robert\OneDrive\Desktop\TempFile.exe

Block of relevant code is below:

```
While 1

$nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
Switch $nMsg
    Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        Exit

    Case $Save
        SaveOptions()

    Case $StartButton
        ;TAB1 of GUI
        
        
If WinExists("[CLASS: QT373947473845]") Then
$oBlah = WinGetHandle("[CLASS: QT373947473845]")
$BSLoc = WinGetPos ("[CLASS: QT373947473845]")

If $BSLoc[0] <> 0 or $BSLoc[1] <> 0 or $BSLoc[2] <> 800 or $BSLoc[3] <> 600 Then
WinSetState ( $oBlah, "", @SW_MINIMIZE )

sleep(500)
WinActivate($oBlah)
WinWaitActive($oBlah)
WinMove($oBlah, "", 0, 0, 800, 600)
sleep(2000)
Else
WinActivate($oBlah)
WinWaitActive($oBlah)
sleep(2000)
EndIf

Endif
EndSwitch
WEnd
```

I have thousands of lines of other code within the case but I tried to limit it as that portion is irrelevant

The Case $StartButton is the line where I am trying to do an OR if run by TaskManager. I have read you cannot do an OR function within a switch case but if you do 2 cases without a break it is the same thing?

I read some documentation and saw I can add a “/prim1=value” to the end of the command line and it will pass the prim1 argument to $CmdLine[0] but I can’t seem to get it working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the [documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm).
Particularly this part:

> So if you were to use the compiled executable by passing commandline
> parameters:
> `myProg.exe param1 "This is a string parameter" 99`
> `$CmdLine[0] ; this equals 3` (because there are 3 command line parameters)
> `$CmdLine[1] ; This contains "param1".`
> `$CmdLine[2] ; This contains "This is a string parameter".`
> `$CmdLine[3] ; This contains 99.`

So then just modify the code so that it behaves differently if `$CmdLine[1] = something`.

As for the switch case: that is inside of a message loop for the GUI and the code in the `Case $StartButton` part of the switch block is run when the start button is pressed and `$nMsg` is equal to the control ID of the start button (`$StartButton`).

If you want to run this code at some other time what I would do it just move all of that code into its own function:

```
Func onStartClick()
    ; start button code here
Endfunc
```

And then just call `onStartClick()` in the switch block:

```
$nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
Switch $nMsg
    Case $StartButton
        onStartClick()
    Case $someOtherButton
        ; someOtherButton code...etc
EndSwitch
```

And then you can also call this function if there is a particular command line param (place this code *before* the Switch...EndSwitch block, not inside it):

```
If $CmdLine[0] >= 1 And $CmdLine[1] = "param1" then
    ; other code to run when started with "program.exe param1"
    onStartClick()
EndIf
```

So the entire thing would look like this:

```
Func onStartClick()
    ; start button code here
Endfunc

If $CmdLine[0] >= 1 And $CmdLine[1] = "param1" then
    ; other code to run when started with "param1"
    onStartClick()
EndIf

$nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
Switch $nMsg
    Case $StartButton
        onStartClick()
    Case $someOtherButton
        ; someOtherButton code...etc
EndSwitch
```